# Selenium iterate multiple elements with same class and print each sub content (another same class)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

with Python, do someone know how to solve this step?:

There is a webpage with multiple elements with class name "tag", and inside them, each one has one element called class= "value",

I want to order that scrap, and set "value".text in each "tag" variable

Sometimes there is not going to be all the tags, so I need a condition too:

```
    <div class="tag">
    "Dog"
    </div>
    <div class="value"> the dog name is Sam
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="tag">
    "Cat"
    </div>
    <div class="value"> the cat name is Jam
  </div>
</div>
```

expected output:

dog= the dog name is Sam

cat= the cat name is Jam

```
tags=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'tag')

for tag in tags:... 
      if tag.text == 'Dog': 
          dog= ...... .text

.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tagValue = {}
for tag in tags:
      if tag.text not in tagValue:
         tagValue[tag.text] = value.text #get this element by following sibling xpath
```